# A-frame and ar.js: Scan QR code with <a-camera>

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm building an application that needs to seamlessly present data on an AR marker, dependent on the last QR code scanned (user shouldn't ever have to leave the web-app). If a QR code can't be scanned in an a-camera, is there any other approach to accomplishing this?